# ¿Como puedo manejar elementos con vistas distintas en una lista en Android?

Tags: java, android

Quiero crear una lista con elementos que tienen diferentes vistas (`View`) con sus propios *layouts*. Por ejemplo: un elemento con textos, y otro con una imagen.

No he encontrado documentación en español sobre el tema. Existe la posibilidad, que componentes puedo usar. Un ejemplo sería bienvenido.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Si no sabes cómo hacer lo que describes en tu pregunta, investiga primero y actualiza tu pregunta con los enlaces de la investigación que hayas hecho. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Para los que se sienten convocado de votar la pregunta para abajo: Se puede solucionar con `RecyclerView`, sin embargo la documentación oficial no esta traducida a español todavía y es realmente difícil de encontrar tutoriales en español. Tomando eso en cuenta, la pregunta no es mala, y el tema es de interés común.

Comment: Pregunta demasiada amplia, no se porque la desean reabir! =|.